# How can we specify organization level permissions using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am new to Django authentication and Authorisation , we have a login and signup implemented with ReactJS on the client side and the Django JWT authentication on the server side. Now, I want to take this to next level by adding authorisation aswell by making users from same organizations only must be able to view/read/write the data existing in the application. Every user will be identified using a specific domain name ex: @gmail.com,@xyz.com. Users from one domain must not have any access to the database of the other organizations.
I think we can achieve this with Permissions concept in Django but dont know how we can do it technically. Any ideas are well appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple approaches, but I mostly handle this kind of stuff in the views, you can filter out the user's email and then can compare inside the views.
just an example:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world(request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user.email == re.match(r"... regex here ...", user):  # regex
            return Response({"message": "Got some data of the organization xyz!", "data": request.data})
        else: 
             return Response({"message": "Not authorized for XYZ operations!", "data": request.data})
```

This feels simple but understandable approach for me. And most often I follow this.

Comment: Thanks @Faisal , I understand that you have tried to produce emails of the same organization aside and send it in a response. I would like to know after categorising the users how can we differentiate the database for the other user groups. The database served across the organization is the same but not the data inside it.